# Possible to bring UIPickerView ahead of UIAlertView?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uialertview, uipickerview

I am developing an app, there i want to bring my picker in front of UIAlertView is it possible to do achieve this ? (without dismissing my alertView)

Here is my screenshot attached
[image]:
**Please help, and thank in advance!**

Comment: Not easily. Alert views are for alerts , read the hig

Answer (score 0):

**UIAlertView** will catch all UI events when it's displayed. I think you should replace UIAlertView with a customization implementation in UIView level. Like [AlertView](https://github.com/quannguyen90/AlertView)